# 90s book about a man sent back in time to alter outcome of the Cuban Missile Crisis

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

In a future, caste based society a man is caught leading a double life and marrying outside of his caste. In exchange for staying with his family, he agrees to travel back in time to prevent a particular caste from ever coming into existence. The critical event that needs to be changed is the Cuban Missile Crisis.

I read the book in the mid to late 90s. I believe the cover art was a picture of a globe with a man running on top with prism like rays of light coming from where his foot touches the globe.

Comment: And for the millionth time... When did you read this? How old do you think the book might be? Can you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: Sorry, I should have though of that. Details added.

Comment: You might find https://www.librarything.com/topic/75640 useful

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I don't see anything in that discussion that looks like what I'm looking for. Although, I think some of those titles have turned up in my previous attempts at googling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is *Dead Morn* by Piers Anthony (1990). From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/230975.Dead_Morn):

> In the 25th century survivors of the nuclear war must live underground. Their actions must be regulated. Their passions must be controlled.
>
> Love is a crime, and when a man dares to take a lover of his own choice, he must be punished.
>
> It's time for a change and the only way to alter this grim future is to journey back to the past...
>
> And change a few small details.

The front cover matches your description too:

[image: Dead Morn cover]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Based on the description, you might be right, but you could make this a better answer by showing how this book matches the details in the question.

Comment: "With humankind surviving underground in the twenty-fifth-century's last city, a courageous man journeys back in time into Cuba's history to try to alter the past and stop the worldwide conflagration that would leave Earth a nuclear wasteland." Is part of the description for the book in various sites.

Comment: That's it. Thanks, this has been bugging me for years.